# x11 forwarding: Server has no GPU - and no swrast_dri.so

Tags: ssh, debian, x11forwarding, opengl

I am trying to set up my server so that I can use Chromium remotely, which I need to put away some of the silly IP restrictions... Therefore, I need to utilize X11 forwarding and - apparently? - need to have OpenGL available.

First, some info of the hardware:

- The connecting client is: macOS 10.14, XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)
- The server to which I want to connect to is...

This:

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

(The preview kept formatting that code weird, so I had to do a split here, sorry for that!)

Now, whenever I launch Chromium, I immediately get messages that `swrast_dri.so` was not found, which turns out to be a software renderer. Also, running `xdriinfo` came up with this (some noise due to `ssh -v`):

```
# xdriinfo 
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 5 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 44410
debug1: x11_connect_display: $DISPLAY is launchd
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
Screen 0: not direct rendering capable.
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
```

So, I learned that I need to install some kind of video driver. Since my Mac has an embedded Intel GPU (Mid. 2015 MacBook Pro), I decided to install Mesa, in hopes that this would fix the problem - which it did not. So far, I installed these:

```
# dpkg -l | grep -i mesa
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                  13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64               13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64               13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                 13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                  9.0.0-2.1                              amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64              9.0.0-2.1                              amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libosmesa6:amd64                    13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libosmesa6-dev:amd64                13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension -- development files
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64          13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-common-dev:amd64               13.0.6-1+b2                            amd64        Developer documentation for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                          8.3.0-3                                amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
# dpkg -l | grep -i x11
ii  libfontenc1:amd64                   1:1.1.3-1+b2                           amd64        X11 font encoding library
ii  libice-dev:amd64                    2:1.0.9-2                              amd64        X11 Inter-Client Exchange library (development headers)
ii  libice6:amd64                       2:1.0.9-2                              amd64        X11 Inter-Client Exchange library
ii  libqt5x11extras5:amd64              5.7.1~20161021-2                       amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras
ii  libsm-dev:amd64                     2:1.2.2-1+b3                           amd64        X11 Session Management library (development headers)
ii  libsm6:amd64                        2:1.2.2-1+b3                           amd64        X11 Session Management library
ii  libtk8.6:amd64                      8.6.6-1+b1                             amd64        Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11 v8.6 - run-time files
ii  libva-x11-1:amd64                   1.7.3-2                                amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- X11 runtime
ii  libx11-6:amd64                      2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1                       amd64        X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-data                         2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1                       all          X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-dev:amd64                    2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1                       amd64        X11 client-side library (development headers)
ii  libx11-xcb-dev:amd64                2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1                       amd64        Xlib/XCB interface library (development headers)
ii  libx11-xcb1:amd64                   2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1                       amd64        Xlib/XCB interface library
ii  libxau-dev:amd64                    1:1.0.8-1                              amd64        X11 authorisation library (development headers)
ii  libxau6:amd64                       1:1.0.8-1                              amd64        X11 authorisation library
ii  libxaw7:amd64                       2:1.0.13-1+b2                          amd64        X11 Athena Widget library
ii  libxcomposite1:amd64                1:0.4.4-2                              amd64        X11 Composite extension library
ii  libxdamage-dev:amd64                1:1.1.4-2+b3                           amd64        X11 damaged region extension library (development headers)
ii  libxdamage1:amd64                   1:1.1.4-2+b3                           amd64        X11 damaged region extension library
ii  libxdmcp-dev:amd64                  1:1.1.2-3                              amd64        X11 authorisation library (development headers)
ii  libxdmcp6:amd64                     1:1.1.2-3                              amd64        X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
ii  libxext-dev:amd64                   2:1.3.3-1+b2                           amd64        X11 miscellaneous extensions library (development headers)
ii  libxext6:amd64                      2:1.3.3-1+b2                           amd64        X11 miscellaneous extension library
ii  libxfixes-dev:amd64                 1:5.0.3-1                              amd64        X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library (development headers)
ii  libxfixes3:amd64                    1:5.0.3-1                              amd64        X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library
ii  libxfont1:amd64                     1:1.5.2-4                              amd64        X11 font rasterisation library
ii  libxfont2:amd64                     1:2.0.1-3+deb9u1                       amd64        X11 font rasterisation library
ii  libxi6:amd64                        2:1.7.9-1                              amd64        X11 Input extension library
ii  libxinerama1:amd64                  2:1.1.3-1+b3                           amd64        X11 Xinerama extension library
ii  libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64            0.7.1-2~deb9u1                         amd64        library to create keymaps with the XKB X11 protocol
ii  libxkbfile1:amd64                   1:1.0.9-2                              amd64        X11 keyboard file manipulation library
ii  libxmu6:amd64                       2:1.1.2-2                              amd64        X11 miscellaneous utility library
ii  libxmuu1:amd64                      2:1.1.2-2                              amd64        X11 miscellaneous micro-utility library
ii  libxpm-dev:amd64                    1:3.5.12-1                             amd64        X11 pixmap library (development headers)
ii  libxpm4:amd64                       1:3.5.12-1                             amd64        X11 pixmap library
ii  libxrandr2:amd64                    2:1.5.1-1                              amd64        X11 RandR extension library
ii  libxss-dev:amd64                    1:1.2.2-1                              amd64        X11 Screen Saver extension library (development headers)
ii  libxss1:amd64                       1:1.2.2-1                              amd64        X11 Screen Saver extension library
ii  libxt-dev:amd64                     1:1.1.5-1                              amd64        X11 toolkit intrinsics library (development headers)
ii  libxt6:amd64                        1:1.1.5-1                              amd64        X11 toolkit intrinsics library
ii  libxtst6:amd64                      2:1.2.3-1                              amd64        X11 Testing -- Record extension library
ii  libxv1:amd64                        2:1.0.11-1                             amd64        X11 Video extension library
ii  libxvmc1:amd64                      2:1.0.10-1                             amd64        X11 Video extension library
ii  libxxf86dga1:amd64                  2:1.1.4-1+b3                           amd64        X11 Direct Graphics Access extension library
ii  libxxf86vm-dev:amd64                1:1.1.4-1+b2                           amd64        X11 XFree86 video mode extension library (development headers)
ii  libxxf86vm1:amd64                   1:1.1.4-1+b2                           amd64        X11 XFree86 video mode extension library
ii  tk                                  8.6.0+9                                amd64        Toolkit for Tcl and X11 (default version) - windowing shell
ii  tk-dev:amd64                        8.6.0+9                                amd64        Toolkit for Tcl and X11 (default version) - development files
ii  tk8.6                               8.6.6-1+b1                             amd64        Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11 v8.6 - windowing shell
ii  tk8.6-dev:amd64                     8.6.6-1+b1                             amd64        Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11 v8.6 - development files
ii  x11-common                          1:7.7+19                               all          X Window System (X.Org) infrastructure
ii  x11-utils                           7.7+3+b1                               amd64        X11 utilities
ii  x11-xkb-utils                       7.7+3+b1                               amd64        X11 XKB utilities
ii  x11proto-core-dev                   7.0.31-1                               all          X11 core wire protocol and auxiliary headers
ii  x11proto-damage-dev                 1:1.2.1-2                              all          X11 Damage extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-dri2-dev                   2.8-2                                  all          X11 DRI2 extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-fixes-dev                  1:5.0-2                                all          X11 Fixes extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-gl-dev                     1.4.17-1                               all          X11 OpenGL extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-input-dev                  2.3.2-1                                all          X11 Input extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-kb-dev                     1.0.7-1                                all          X11 XKB extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-render-dev                 2:0.11.1-2                             all          X11 Render extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev              1.2.2-1                                all          X11 Screen Saver extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-xext-dev                   7.3.0-1                                all          X11 various extension wire protocol
ii  x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev            2.3.1-2                                all          X11 Video Mode extension wire protocol
```

Now mind you, this is obviously a Debian Server installation and I am litterally trying to add some kind of "desktop-y" stuff to it, which is very much something someone shouldn't do unless they know what they are doing. And to be fair - I do not know everything myself here.

So how do I get that missing `swrast_dri.so` and stop having Chromium complain about it being missing and mis-rendering completely? Because all I get is a big, blue box with pretty much nothing I can click. :)

Kind regards,
Ingwie.